# Completely incorrect machine learning-generated answers

Tags: discussion, support, declined-flags, low-quality-posts

There's a new website out there called [Ask Roboflow](https://ask.roboflow.ai/), which learns from questions and answers posted on Stack Exchange sites and attempts to generate an answer for a particular question. The site tends to generate answers of... questionable correctness, which is [acknowledged](https://medium.com/@braddwyer/introducing-ask-roboflow-a77755d72956) by the author of the site (bold emphasis mine):

> [...] while the output does produce some convincing answers, one drawback of optimizing the network only on predicting the next word of the sentence is that it has no way to optimize for *correctness* of the answer as a whole.
>
> For example, take the question “What color is the apple?” If the canonical answer is “The apple is red,” the following two answers would get the same “accuracy” score: “The apple is green” and “An apple is Red” (each one got 3/4 words correct). But, clearly, it should lose more “points” for missing “red” than for missing “the”.
>
> This drawback means that **Ask Roboflow isn’t yet useful for answer real peoples’ programming questions.** But it is certainly a fun diversion!

So the site itself is all a bit of fun and games right now. However, I came across at least one new user posting answers to questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55987454/2605758), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55987619/2605758)) that are exact copies of answers generated from Ask Roboflow ([1](https://ask.roboflow.ai/question/55987424), [2](https://ask.roboflow.ai/question/55987140)).

How should these be dealt with? The user acknowledges in a comment on the first post that they were "joking with this answer" (and then provides a useful code snippet in the comment, which would make a far better answer!), so the answers are practically useless. In these specific cases, I tried to flag these as VLQ, but these were declined. Should they have been given a NAA or mod flag instead?

Comment: Eeek! those answers are really nonsense

Comment: (side note: too bad that the robot learn to use ["Update:"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127639/when-is-edit-update-appropriate-in-a-post))

Comment: It's bizarre to read some "answers" on that site. It feels like English that was written by someone whose brain isn't working properly, hence it's somewhat surreal. Also some of them are completely hilarious.

Comment: @Clonkex Oh exactly, it's trying act like professional writing, but it's making it worse, doesn't sound like english

Comment: Oh my god! https://ask.roboflow.ai/question/7571635 it is not even python code, let along solving the problem...

Comment: omg, tested with an [unanswered question](https://ask.roboflow.ai/question/55137437) and, well I don't even know what the robot's talking about here.. mistakes were made, adjustments seem needed.

Comment: Apparently, that site is attracting big interest from politicians.

Comment: ["This call will cause a Hibernate pooling to attempt to fettle the file into a different database than in the main() method. You'll have to override the gravity by calling ColbrowseSheet on a Client. However, SQL server keep 443 up operation on everything you have done so."](https://ask.roboflow.ai/question/3801730) this must be what Big Bang Theory and "hacker" movies have been using to generate their scripts. Time to make a GUI interface in visual basic to track some IPs. Also what language is [this](https://ask.roboflow.ai/question/61634)?

Comment: On a more cynical note this site would probably be great for making artificial SEO boosting, keyword stuffed sites (not that I'm trying to give anyone ideas, please don't do that).

Comment: [Oblig XKCD](https://xkcd.com/810/) (language warning)

Comment: OMG, it takes too much time to generate a stupid answer... I usually answer way faster

Comment: I had an (admittedly rather weird) idea for this; train Google's search engine algorithms on the auto generated keyword gibberish, and if it resembles gibberish too much maybe they can detect keyword stuffing sites and exclude them from results? Maybe it could be used to separate [individual answer "signals" from noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_component_analysis)?

Answer (score 70):

While generated, the posts are not outright gibberish and *technically* attempts at answering, so the VLQ and NAA flags don’t apply. Moreover, VLQ and NAA flags are handed to a review queue where regular users help keep the site clean, but they have no power to deal with the underlying problem: someone using Roboflow for their own entertainment at the expense of people that came to Stack Overflow for help.

It's best that the moderator team handle cases like these. We can look at the account and determine if anything other than deleting the posts and issuing a warning suffices. We don’t take abuses like these lightly, but if it’s a regular account that didn’t think the joke through a simple reminder to take the fun elsewhere should be enough.

In this case I dealt with this account by deleting it. It was created solely  to play this joke. I’ve also left comments for the question owners to explain what those strange answers were about and why they are now gone.

So if you recognise more such nonsense in future as roboflow generated, feel free to flag for moderator attention next time. A sample custom flag along the lines of:

> This answer and others by this account are copied from ask.roboflow.ai, a site that uses machine learning to generate answers that ‘look’ plausible. Can these please be removed?

This helps us busy moderators to understand the situation. Bhargav rejected your VLQ flag precisely because it wasn’t clear to him why the post was deemed gibberish (we are usually not subject experts so we can’t always spot a nonsense answer).

Comment: have you forgot to recommend including a link to roboflow original into flag message? Or maybe you prefer that moderators do needed googling themselves :)

Comment: Sounds to me like this still is some kind of plagiarism, when the actual source of the answer is not mentioned.

Comment: @Holger: yes, it's blatant copying of work by someone (or some*thing* at least) else.

Comment: Well, Roboflow as an automated processing does not add to ownership, so the ownership still is at the people who created the original answers that got mixed and scrambled. Since Roboflow does state that the texts originate from Stackoverflow, it might be sufficient (ianal), but the minimum, somebody copying an answer from there has to do, is to link to Roboflow as a source, to allow to trace it back (but good luck trying to name all original authors…).

Comment: @Holger: we all mix knowledge we gleaned from various sources; the ML approach by Roboflow does not scramble answer snippets, it has built a model of sentence structure and word frequencies to build similar sentences from, so it is not dissimilar from how we build sentences. It's just that any actual understanding of the subject matter is missing. That someone is copying this wholesale is a much smaller problem than the fact that the only reason to do this is as a form of entertainment at the expense of whomever put in the effort to ask a real question.

Comment: “It's just that any actual understanding of the subject matter is missing.”—That’s what makes it “automated processing”. Roboflow does not mix knowledge, but textual data taken from Stackoverflow. The actual rules it uses, are irrelevant. The laws might differ from country to country, but at least in Germany, the authorship does not change when data is automatically processed. I know, that someone posts nonsense answers just for fun, creates more annoyance, but still, to me, it also sounds like a plagiarism issue. Of course, if the user linked to the Roboflow source, the annoyance would stay.

Comment: @Holger - I've been interested in whether Roboflow itself has plagiarized anyone and, despite extensive Googling of its output, I haven't found any instances of that yet. The model itself doesn't contain any of the original text, only the weights it has learned from them.

Comment: @BradDwyer Roboflow doesn’t plagiarize anyone. It can’t plagiarize, as said, because it is just an automated processing. Since it’s processing uses a lot of input from different individual authors, you would have to attribute the result to a lot of common authors, if not the entire Stackoverflow community, and the publication of Roboflow’s result adheres to the CC license in that regard by naming Stackoverflow as the source. And well, yes, the way it processes the input, you can’t trace back the results to the original input, but that has no meaning to the law.

Comment: "Plagiarize" may not be the proper term since it implies some sort of moral judgement. I simply meant "verbatim copy" -- none of the sentences I've searched have been said by a human before. As @MartijnPieters mentioned, this is a lot like human output where you've learned from an innumerable number of other sources but are capable of producing your own output that isn't simply a remix of those inputs. On a theoretically level it's not 100% clear to me that these are entirely analogous or entirely different; I think that's still an open theoretical question.

Answer (score 41):

I handled the flags there. I admit that I was a bit surprised to see that you had flagged a post wrongly, as I usually have found you on point with your flags. Anyway, I spent a couple of minutes there, and it seemed like a valid answer to me. I also read your comment there:

> Please stop posting useless answers from roboverflow.

and searched "roboverflow", but there was no good results for that. So I just declined both the flags and moved on.

Henceforth, don't use the NAA or VLQ flags for posts where we need to have way more context. (Also, the only reason I checked your comment on the post, was because the queue was a bit free today and I was also not getting sleep, I can't guarantee that to be the case everyday). Whenever there needs any additional context, use the other flag and clearly explain the issue. That said, thank you for bringing this issue forward, Martijn has already taken care of the account.

Comment: Yeah, that was a mistake on my part, I completely messed up the name of the site there (hence why I later deleted the comment). In hindsight I probably should've mod-flagged it to begin with, but it's taken care of now.

Answer (score 36):

I wanted to chime in as I'm the creator of Ask Roboflow.

First, it's certainly *not* my intention for anyone to be cross-posting the AI-generated answers back to Stack Overflow. While I've seen a few that are pretty close to coherent answers, most are nowhere near the quality needed to be considered helpful (yet).

My goal over the long-term is to improve the quality of the answers, especially for common newbie questions that get asked ad-infinitum.

I hope that if newbies can get their easy answers from a robot they won't feel the need to post so many duplicates which can free up the time of the human moderators to do more useful things.

Unfortunately I don't have any useful suggestions on what to do about jerks spamming cross-posted answers (other than what is already done for trolls and spammers). I assume the novelty of that will wear off relatively quickly.

---

### Update:

Per @Gary99's suggestion, I have added a watermark to answers generated by Ask Roboflow so that they can be easily detected and filtered programmatically. The first closing tag (usually `</p>` or `</code>`) is now prepended by the following invisible Unicode string:

```
&#x200c;&#x200c;&#x200c;&#x200b;&#x200b;&#x200c;&#x200b;&#x200c;&#x200c;&#x200b;&#x200c;&#x200c;&#x200c;&#x200c;&#x200c;&#x200c;&#x200b;&#x200b;&#x200b;&#x200c;&#x200b;&#x200c;&#x200c;&#x200b;&#x200c;&#x200c;&#x200c;&#x200c;
```

Which is the binary encoding of the ASCII representation of `robo` where `0` is represented by `ZERO WIDTH SPACE` (`U+200B`) and `1` is represented by `ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER` (`U+200C`).

An example to confirm that these characters are not stripped when copy/pasting (these invisible characters should be at the end of the first line):

```
You can `install‌‌‌​​‌​‌‌​‌‌‌‌‌‌​​​‌​‌‌​‌‌‌‌` a package using `git add` (which is the same only in the latest build of an Angular table).

    npm install setup.js

Good luck.
```

If you copy/paste the above text into this [non-printable Unicode character visualizer](https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php) you should see the watermark flowing all the way through:

[image: Visualization of the invisible characters]

<s>Update 2: I’m going to have to change this a bit; the Mongolian Vowel Separator is apparently not invisible on iOS. I’ll update with the new watermark string once I swap it out.</s>

Update 3: [Updated the Unicode characters used in the encoding to be invisible across all browsers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56048048/ios-displaying-invisible-unicode-characters-as-dotted-box-containing-mvs) (Thanks to @iBug for the U+200C suggestion and @the_ress_ for noticing the original bug in iOS)

Update 4: Fixed license note and original question links.

Comment: The purpose of Stack Overflow is **not** to answer questions over and over again. The purpose of Stack Overflow is to create a knowledge base where one can find high-quality answers to high-quality questions. You do not fill a knowledge base with 10000 answers to 10000 questions which are all the same. You have maybe 100 questions which deal with the same subject, pointing to a single question whose answers answer all 100 questions. Even if you were able to generate good answers to those 10000 questions, we don't want that, because searching for the answer gives you 10000 answers to parse.

Comment: That's great, Stack Overflow can continue to do whatever they think is best for Stack Overflow. I'm working on what I believe will be better for new coders.

Comment: This robot is never going to actually physically post answers on Stack Overfllow, right? It's just going to answer them in the moment when a novice asks it something, so said novice does not even have to make the effort of going to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. It's a separate site without write-access to Stack Overflow and I don't anticipate ever requesting access to the write API unless it someday gets *really* good.

Comment: There is author attribution, but isn't a direct link to the original question on Stack Overflow required (there is only a generic `https://stackoverflow.com/`)? [Sample](https://ask.roboflow.ai/question/61634). From *[A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What should I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177)*: *"Simple **links to the original post** and author info are just fine."* (my emphasis)

Comment: *"[Hyperlink directly to the original question on the source site (e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/)"*

Comment: [The license must also be linked to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177) - `http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/` (*"You have to link the license and allow other people to use your content, as long as they follow these very same rules."*).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out; when I moved the content template from the stackroboflow.com domain I forgot the data source license info was on a different subpage. I've added it now. I also added the link to the question (I, stupidly, had only considered that since the person who posted it had to copy the link they knew where it came from.. but obviously anyone reading after the fact would have a harder time finding it!)