# Is there "no correlation between question content and upvotes/views"?

Tags: discussion, questions, downvotes, voting, upvotes

[stackroboflow.com](https://stackroboflow.com/) is an AI created to generate questions on StackOverflow.

Its author [states](https://stackroboflow.com/about/index.html):

> Originally, I wanted to predict the number of upvotes and views
>   questions would get (which, intuitively, I thought would be a good
>   proxy for their quality). Unfortunately, after working on this for
>   about a week straight I've come to the conclusion that there is no
>   correlation between question content and upvotes/views.
>
> I tried several different models (including adapting an `AWD_LSTM`
>   classifier, a random forest on a bag of words, and using Google's
>   AutoML) and none of them produced anything better than random noise.
>
> I also tried using myself as a "human classifier" and given two random
>   questions from StackOverflow I can't predict which one will be more
>   popular.
>
> This was a surprising result for me and I wasted a lot of time trying
>   to tackle what turned out to be an intractible problem.
>
> It might be possible that with other data besides the question text a
>   machine learning model may be able to do a better prediction (the date
>   posted, for instance, seems like it might be a valuable datapoint) but
>   that's beyond my abilities for right now.

Wow. That's a bold claim, isn't it?

And an easy one to test. If what he says is true then an account that only posts questions copypasted from his AI would have *at least* the same average amount of downvotes and upvotes. This would mean that this account's reputation would grow, and in particular, such an account would not get questionbanned.

Full disclosure now... I did found [an account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11465967/display-name?tab=profile) for this purpose. I intended to post questions from this account at a very moderate pace and obey all restrictions that would be placed on this account should the questions be received poorly (like mandatory 1 day long period between questions and such). I was just so curious to test the aforementioned bold claim...

I even posted one question from this account. But then time of consideration started… Well, **if** the questions would be received well, then there would be nothing wrong in my little experiment? And if the guy would be proven right, if SO's voting system would be thus disproven, then it would have profound implications, wouldn't it? But still, I had... Pangs of conscience. So I flagged my own Q with a custom flag and explained the mod the situation. The Q is now gone.

Still, the topic still intrigues me. Is there any study? data? finding? argument? that would disprove the statements from stackroboflow's author I quoted?

<sub>Because I take it I should rather not carry on my idea for an experiment, right?</sub>

Comment: You wouldn't happen to behind [this issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/384596/1197934), would you?

Comment: @fbueckert No. That wasn't me.

Comment: *I've come to the conclusion that there is no correlation between question content and upvotes/views.* - Aren't some tags more popular than others? Saying there's no correlation between content and views would imply all questions have an equal chance of getting viewed regardless of how they're tagged. Am I misunderstanding the statement?

Comment: @BSMP I don't know, ask the guy I'm quoting who said this. I just wanted to test his claims.

Comment: " If what he says is true then an account that only posts questions copypasted from his AI would have at least the same average amount of downvotes and upvotes" Um, no, that's not a direct consequence of his claim being true. Question content (eg. What the question is about) is distinct from question *quality* (eg. How well it's presented). The author is saying that it's hard to use upvotes as an indicator of the bot's quality because some quality questions attract more attention than others, and the author found no correlation between the content and the attention it gets.

Comment: There clearly is correlation because I can spot the high quality audit questions in the Triage review queue a mile off as being better than everything else I see in that queue. Those questions are picked out merely because they have lots of upvotes and no downvotes and it really does show you want a good question looks like when you get one of those audits.

Comment: I don't see anything groundbreaking with the claim (which I read as "I could not figure out AI algorithm to detect usefulness of a text" - not exactly a task I'd expect to be completed in "about a week straight" :) )

Comment: I upvoted this because the central question is an interesting one, and would be worthy of discussion. But I don’t want that upvote to be interpreted as support for you running your own little “experiment” involving filling the site with garbage.

Comment: You might get to be the president of a large country, but grokking how a programmer's question is interesting isn't yet remotely close to AI capabilities.  We get to keep our jobs for at least another decade, could be intentional.  [Related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/384596/17034).

Comment: The author might be correct though. Another factor that the author seems to miss is the age of the post, especially from those [very old questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Votes)... and also Hot Network Questions.

Answer (score 5):

Please do not post questions you don't care about (whether it is created by some tool or just randomly come to your head) - we already have a lot of content to triage without that.

If author of that site would implement "given rough outline of a question automatically improve it to fetch the highest predicted score" (i.e. one can start with simply replacing some words with "better" once) that would be different story - you'd be able to start with question you have and post it as real one (and hence actually support question with comments/edits/answer triage).